# How does importlib.import_module() combat duplicate files when passed a filename?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have a for loop that goes something like this:

```
py_search_path = home/this_directory
foo = 100

for fname in glob.glob(f'{py_search_path}/*.py'):
    fname = os.path.basename(fname)
    fname = ''.join(fname.split())[:-3]

    datareader = importlib.import_module(fname)
    if foo = datareader.baz
        do something cool
```

Where in `home/this_directory` I have a bunch of py files that have variables stored in them like this:

```
baz = (some number)
```

So my datareader is finding these files and then calling the variables values. It works perfectly but I see a future problem where lets say I have a file in `home/this_directory` named `bundy.py` and then I have another file in `home/that_directory` also named `bundy.py` but with a different `baz` value.

So my question is how does import_module handle this type of case? How does it discriminate which file to search through when the only argument that we are passing to it is the filename without the .py extension?

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module, python take it's name, add the '.py' and search for a file with this name into the PYTHON_PATH.
The PYTHON_PATH is basically a list of folders to check, python will iterate over them and stop as soon as it found a matching file to import.

PYTHON_PATH can be set with environment variables and by default usually contain only your working directory or the root of your project if you have an IDE.

So in your case with multiple folders, because `importlib.import_module("bundy")` works I assume either `home/this_directory` and `home/that_directory` are inside the PYTHON_PATH, then python will import the first one in list.

If you want more precision, in your case, you may want to have only `home` in your PYTHON_PATH and provide `that_directory.bundy` and `this_directory.bundy` to the `importlib.import_module` function.